# how to change type of text object font in crystal report to bar code font

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, barcode

I want to convert the number into a bar code format, it works well, and the font file is in the folder of the program, but any computer did not install the ttf file in it, when the conversion prints it empty

```
Dim path = Application.StartupPath & "\IDAutomationHC39M.ttf" '  
pfcbarcode.AddFontFile(path)
Dim br As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject = cr.Section5.ReportObjects("br")
br.ApplyFont(New Font(pfcbarcode.Families(0), 12, FontStyle.Regular))
br.Text = "*" & srchcombopatient.SelectedValue & "*"
```

i try normal font like time new roman , and work , but bar code not work unless we install ttf file inside machine 
the ttf file exists with the program in the other computer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install your font which does not come in crystal report when you installed.

Other than default fonts you need to add that ttf file in a particular location where the all font.

That's why, If you used barcode font in your report, report search that font and it is not installed in that pc where your crystal report stays, so it does not show.

Comment: the ttf file exists with the program in the other computer

Comment: In my case I installed manually. Fyi I am not 100% sure, but for the coding side, you need to create a batch or power cell script and then from code if font not exist, then run this batch or power cell script to install font.